# How to get object value from NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdictionary

I have this bit of code where I put objects into a NSMutableDictionary:

```
SingletonDictionary *sd = [SingletonDictionary sharedDictionary];

UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)sender;  
int tagValue = tf.tag;  //  get the tag value

[sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes setObject:tf.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tagValue]];  //  value found in textField id'd by tag
```

**UPDATED:** This is the code where I'm trying to retrieve the contents of the dictionary:

```
SingletonDictionary *sd = [SingletonDictionary sharedDictionary];  //  initialize
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  //  here too...
sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes = [defaults objectForKey:@"importFileIDs"];  //  move from standardUserDefaults to dictionary singleton

NSLog(@"\n\nsd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes: %@", sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes);


[sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes[intTagValue]]];  //  move contents of textField from dictionary
textField.text = [sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes objectForKey: tagValue];
```

This is the contents of *sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes*:

```
sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes: {
0 = 2;
1 = 5;
2 = 8;
4 = 7;
```

}

The first column is the tag of the UITextField; the 2nd column is the data in that textField

The contents of the dictionary are valid; I got rid of the build errors, but when I run this, there is nothing in the textField.

I have looked and looked at this, and just hope I didn't do something stupid.  Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You're sending a message objectAtIndex:objectForKey: to textField.text. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: What does `[sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes[intTagValue]]` mean?

Comment: You have a syntax error that has absolutely nothing to do with your title or the task that you're trying to perform. You're missing braces on that line. `objectAtIndex:objectForKey:` is not a method. You need braces around the call to `objectAtIndex:`, and then you're going to have to deal with the problem that gnasher already pointed out.

Comment: ...and, as Hot Licks just pointed out, you've got _too many_ braces around that expression. Break that line down into separate, indiviually valid, lines to see what's going on.

Comment: Yep, avoid "long chain polymer" statements, especially when you're trying to understand something.  Using a few temporary variables to carry a value from one line to the next costs literally nothing, but make the code much easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
textField.text = [sd.dictionaryOfUserIndexes objectForKey: [tagValue stringValue]];
```

Thanks everybody for your time; I appreciate it.